# Best program or clipboard manager to trim whitespace from Windows clipboard on copy/paste?

Tags: windows, clipboard

**Is there a program, or a clipboard manager with a plugin** for Windows that can automatically trim the beginning and ending whitespace from text copied into the clipboard before pasting?

I've found **many** clipboard manager programs, but none that specifically list this feature. There is a [discussion in the AutoHotkey forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/57765-trim-leading-and-trailing-white-space-from-the-clipboard/) about doing this, with no solid answer. I emailed the developer of [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) my idea and he said he will try to work this option into his program when he gets the chance.

Is there a good clipboard manager which auto-trims whitespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up every single clipboard manager program and **finally found one that automatically scrubs whitespace from the beginning and end of copied text**.

http://www.clipboardfusion.com/

It can play a sound when the whitespace is "scrubbed" and there are optional find-and-replace options too. Really nice.

Comment: Great answer,  I had forgotten about it! Fusion people have some nice software to improve Windows. (I use DisplayFusion)

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the voice-recognition software [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) to handle copy-pasting operations. By default, I trim the text when I say the command `copy`, which I wrote in advanced scripting, as the following (as you can see it is not very advanced):

```
Sub Main
    Clipboard(Trim(Clipboard))
End Sub
```

[Documentation on Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Returns a string that contains a copy of a specified string without
>   leading spaces (LTrim), without trailing spaces (RTrim), or without
>   leading or trailing spaces (Trim):
>
> ```
> Public Shared Function LTrim(ByVal str As String) As String
> Public Shared Function RTrim(ByVal str As String) As String
> Public Shared Function Trim(ByVal str As String) As String
> ```

PS: (unrelated to Dragon) http://outertech.com/en/clipboard-history does trailing only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24431-convert-text-uppercase-lowercase-capitalized-or-inverted/) to do it with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (scripting language for desktop automation on Windows):

```
~^v::
Trimmed := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "^\s+", "")
Trimmed := RegExReplace(Trimmed, "\s+$", "")
Clipboard = %Trimmed%
return
```

Comment: Thank you Franck for the answer. **A word of warning** to anyone using this; it seems that AutoHotkey is a bit too slow if you copy/paste extremely fast. For now I am using it, but it "misses" what I copy sometimes if I paste immediately. I don't have any knowledge on how AH binds to key combinations to fix this.

Comment: @degenerate Thanks for the edit, yes I guess that's why they use `ClipWait 0.5 ; Wait up to .5 seconds` in the original script. I agree it's quite a pain, I have some similar issues with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting, probably some Windows limitations (but I would be curious to have some in-depth explanations).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The latest version of [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org) (AHK_L) can do it even better. `~^v::Clipboard := Trim(Clipboard, "`r`n `t")`

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sorry, the code is formatted incorrectly. ``~^v::Clipboard := Trim(Clipboard, "`r`n `t")``

Comment: Unfortunately while this answer works, it's still not ideal. Copy-pasting very quickly is too fast for AutoHotkey and it doesn't have the time to edit the clipboard contents before I paste. I am still looking for alternatives if anyone knows one.

Comment: @Avi Your original script had issues when pasting from Excel. Here's a modified version: ``^v::SendInput, % Trim(Clipboard, "`r`n `t")``

Answer (score 1):

[Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io) has this: Special Paste > Trim White Space

You can do more with [Scripting](https://github.com/sabrogden/Ditto/wiki/Scripting) feature in Ditto

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the Spartan clipboard manager. I work for them so I'm biased but it does the job nicely. You even have the option to have it happen when you Ctrl+C then Ctrl+v without having to refer to the program at all.